# Unable to see newly added contacts on Viber for Nexus 7 LTE

Tags: sync, nexus-7, viber-messenger

As title says, I've been looking for a solution to this issue but it seems like its something to do with Viber itself. To describe the issue, I'm using a Nexus 7 LTE version with KitKat 4.4.3. It works perfectly on the device but neither can I search contacts nor see a newly added contact (`before the last update`) under Viber when added through Google's default "**People**" app.

**And soon after the `latest update` I could search for the contacts but not the newly added contacts been seen though the user is a Viber user.**

Quite amazing is that when I switch on **DATA** on my mobile (`which also has the same Viber number configured`) & sync the contacts which then the new contact start to appear on Viber under both Nexus & mobile device.

I don't know whether this is a bug with Viber for Nexus devices as I've not seen any solutions to this so far. An output or advise on this will be great!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Never come across it on any of the Nexus devices here (that's a 4, 5, 7 (2013) and a Nexus 10)  Maybe reach out to the Viber Devs?

Comment: Well, for me I've tried installing twice as a fresh install but still was the same.. I'm fairly sure its not the device but viber.. before it had searching issues, but after the latest update it started working..

Comment: As the Nexus devices get updates fast to Android some apps do go a bit funny as the devs try to update them for the new version. This happens a lot with Whatsapp and others like it. That's why (I'd guess) they've a dev preview of Android L so that devs can get their apps working again, for example Android L can break certain JINI related calls.

Comment: I hope so, but its the other way around for me. Whatsapp shows all the newly added contacts quite happily by updating its contact list but Viber does not.

Comment: I mentioned whatsapp as I didn't work at all in ART initially and had issues with any 4.4.x update initially too.